# Big play buttons appears on phone for html video tag

Tags: ios, iphone, html, css

Added html video tag into my site and placed play button externally as per my need to handle play pause. Works fine in all the devices but except iphone, there is big play button appears on the center of the video when we open with iphone safari http://www.snoozeal.com/

tried many solutions from stack and others but didn't work

here are some css i tried

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
   background: red; 
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display{}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}








video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}

.overlay-video video {pointer-events: none}
.overlay-video video::-webkit-media-controls {display: none !important}


*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
   display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* Old shadow dom for play button */

*::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  display: none!important;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/* New shadow dom for play button */

/* This one works */

*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you solved your play button size problem. FYI, look into the HTML video poster attribute for the default image for your video - in my iPhone it shows as a blank white box right now.

Comment: No please check on any desktop how it is working and on iphone for the issue.
It needs to have like desktop play icon even on iphone

Comment: I don't see a [video poster](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp) on the iPhone - I just see a blank white area where the video is. So your white play button doesn't show up. It's there (though I see that it has a `style=display: none` on it right now). Add a video poster and take off that style.

Answer (score 1):

try this to hide play button on iOS

```
video::-webkit-media-controls{display: none !important;}
```